# python3 flask pyserial script works only once

Tags: python, ajax, flask, pyserial

I want to write a script to open a cash drawer, using a serial device (with USB) instead of opening it everytime the printer prints (e.g. on credit card payments the cash drawer is not needed to be open).

It should work via Ajax call to a Flask based website (the entire website shall act as ajax receiver to perform python scripts).

The Flask website is running, other scripts are running without problems, that's why I show here only the interesting part of the main script:

```
...
@app.route("/cashdrawer")
def cashdrawer():
        import cash_drawer_open
        return "open ?"   # website output
...
```

The cash drawer opener `cash_drawer_open.py` looks like that

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=300,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    xonxoff=serial.XOFF,
    rtscts=False,
    dsrdtr=False
)

ser.write(bytes([0, 4]))

ser.flush()        # something
ser.flushInput()   # I played
ser.flushOutput()  # around
ser.close()        # with
# exit()           # etc.
# quit()           # etc.

print ("open ?")   # terminal output
```

The problem is, that the drawer is opened only once, after the Flask server is started and the script is called for the first time. Each further call of the same website does not return `open ?` in the terminal and the drawer keeps calm. The only thing is the terminal response with

```
192.168.178.29 - - [11/Oct/2017 18:31:56] "GET /cashdrawer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.178.29 - - [11/Oct/2017 18:31:58] "GET /cashdrawer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.178.29 - - [11/Oct/2017 18:32:03] "GET /cashdrawer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

again and again.

What I also tried is to call it with parameters like changing timestamps

```
http://myserver/cashdrawer?t=12765435664543
```

but with no success.

Any ideas how I can speak with the USB unit every time I call the address ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is to assume importing is executing code. It's only for the first time, afterwards an import statement only hands you a cached module instance.

So refactor your code with three easy steps:

1. put the actual logic (anything but the import) in `cash_drawer_open`
   into a *function*
2. place the import of `cash_drawer_open` in your web-app to the top of the module where it belongs
3. at the position of your current import, instead call the function defined in step 1

Comment: OK, now I have `def import_cashdrawer():
        import cash_drawer_open` on top of the main script and `@app.route("/cashdrawer")
def cashdrawer():
        import_cashdrawer()
        return "open now ?"` in the route function, but the same result, it works only once. What am I not getting here ?

Comment: Ah... I am getting it... moment.

Comment: Absolutely confusing to me: it works like expected, when I call the page from a tablet browser. When I use the MacBook, with Safari or FF, the page hangs/freezes UNTIL I call the page again from the tablet. Then it fires twice... aarrrgh !

Comment: Found answer: activate threaded like this `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True,debug=True)`